# Does ResourceManager load all cultures automatically?

Tags: c#, localization, globalization, resourcemanager

I have a class library - call it Framework. In the assemblyinfo.cs, I have:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]
```

Under a \Resources\ directory, I have **FrameworkResources.resx** and **FrameworkResources.fr-FR.resx**

In a helper class, I am using this as my resource manager:

```
private static ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager("Framework.Resources.FrameworkResources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

In code, if I do something like this:

```
String message = manager.GetString("ArgumentNullExceptionMessage", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

I can debug and hover over CurrentCulture and it (and UICulture) are set to fr-FR, yet this ALWAYS brings back my default, english message - NOT the French message from the fr-FR resource file.

Should ResourceManager automatically wire that up, or should I be writing code to query the current culture, then open the right file? Am I incorrect in assuming that Resource Manager will know to get the fr-FR string, because that is the current culture?

I'm not sure why this isn't working.

**UPDATE:**
I have satellite assemblies, so believe the compilation part is going OK. I think the problem is in my resource manager. I tried using ResourceSets and using ResourceManager explicitly like this:

```
ResourceManager manager =
    new ResourceManager("Framework.Resources.FrameworkResources",
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

Debug.WriteLine("de-DE : " + manager.GetString(resourceName, new CultureInfo("de-DE")));
Debug.WriteLine("el    : " + manager.GetString(resourceName, new CultureInfo("el")));
Debug.WriteLine("es-MX : " + manager.GetString(resourceName, new CultureInfo("es-MX")));
Debug.WriteLine("fr-FR : " + manager.GetString(resourceName, new CultureInfo("fr-FR")));
Debug.WriteLine("hi    : " + manager.GetString(resourceName, new CultureInfo("hi")));
Debug.WriteLine("zh-CN : " + manager.GetString(resourceName, new CultureInfo("zh-CN")));
```

That results in this:

> ```
> de-DE : Argument '%ArgumentName%' cannot be null or empty.
> el    : Argument '%ArgumentName%' cannot be null or empty.
> es-MX : Argument '%ArgumentName%' cannot be null or empty.
> fr-FR : Argument '%ArgumentName%' cannot be null or empty.
> hi    : Argument '%ArgumentName%' cannot be null or empty.
> zh-CN : Argument '%ArgumentName%' cannot be null or empty.
> ```

So, even though everything is in place, my resource manager simply isn't trying to look in those satellite assemblies. And to be clear, in those assemblies, I have the translated version of the string above - so it's definitely reading from my default FrameworkResources.resx file, instead of the culture-specific ones.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, that's correct already. Have you checked your output folder - are the satellite assemblies being created appropriately?

Comment: Yes - in \bin\Debug, I have Framework.dll, then I have a fr-FR sub-directory, and within in, I have Framework.resources.dll - does that sound right?

Comment: I'm not particularly experienced in this area, but it sounds right to me, yes.

Comment: Does your code change culture at all? I wonder whether the current culture for the executing thread isn't the same as the current culture in the debugger. Maybe *log* the current culture just before retrieving the message.

Comment: Yes, it appears correctly everywhere. I have been stepping through the code - where I can observe CultureInfo.CurrentCulture set to fr-FR. I also did a Debug.WriteLine to be safe, and that said the same thing. I even point to Resources.FrameworkResource.Culture - and change the culture on the actual resource manage. Everyone reports have fr-FR, yet I continue to get en-US messages. And yes, I did confirm I REALLY have french messages in my fr-FR resource file :-)

Comment: I found part of the problem - I think. When I rename (or create a new resource file) that isn't Resource1.resx, the IDE blows away the designer file. So, only my default .resx has a code-behind, all the other languages have designer files, but they are empty, and contiunue to be empty after the build!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out (thanks to more scouring on the interweb). I was running code from unit tests, and apperently MSTest doesn't "deploy" the satellite assemblies. If I go into the Test Settings and turn off "Deployment", everything works as expected. Ugh!